# Faço uma nova questão ou reformulo a pergunta e ofereço uma recompensa?

Tags: suporte, pergunta-específica, recompensa

Há um  tempo atrás eu postei esta pergunta: [Pegar conteúdo de outra página por javascript ou jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68997/pegar-conte%C3%BAdo-de-outra-p%C3%A1gina-por-javascript-ou-jquery)
A resposta do amigo @SneepS NinjA funciona no site. Eu testei em localhost e realmente funciona, o problema é quando eu tento colocar no [site](https://ebookstore.xtechcommerce.com/acessorios/colares).

Ele não funciona, ele dá o seguinte erro:

```
Bloqueado carregamento de conteúdo ativo mesclado “http://projetos.lucaspeperaio.com.br/ajax-cross-domain/jquery.xdomainajax.js”
```

Eu não quero que as pessoas marquem minha questão como duplicata, pois atrapalha no tempo de resposta da minha pergunta.

Então eu reformulo a questão e ofereço uma recompensa? Ou eu faço outra questão?

Se eu reformular a pergunta acredito que vai se tornar outra pergunta por que é erro diferente da primeira pergunta. (mas eu não tenho certeza)

Para evitar problemas futuros e discussões futuras queria saber o que eu faço. (Pois preciso de alguma forma de pegar conteúdo de outra página que não dê erro)

Comment: Deves fazer uma nova pergunta senão vai virar [pergunta camaleão](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=pergunta+camaleão)

Comment: Concordo, porém tem muitos aqui que colocam um monte de questão como duplicata mesmo tendo algumas diferenças. (Já aconteceu muito comigo)

Comment: Tens de referir na nova pergunta "Tomando em conta [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68997/pegar-conte%C3%BAdo-de-outra-p%C3%A1gina-por-javascript-ou-jquery) que funcionou bem mo meu localhost mas não funciona agora no site" e explicas o problema atual só.

Comment: Vou postar desta maneira que você falou, obrigado.

Comment: @JorgeB. responde.

Comment: @bigown feito...

Answer (score 6):

Deves fazer uma nova pergunta senão vai virar [pergunta camaleão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=pergunta%20camale%C3%A3o).

Tens de referir na nova pergunta:

"Tomando em conta [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68997/pegar-conte%C3%BAdo-de-outra-p%C3%A1gina-por-javascript-ou-jquery) que funcionou bem no meu localhost mas não funciona agora no site" e explicas o problema atual só."

Comment: Existe algumas questões parecidas, porém não consigo chamar outro conteúdo via ajax com nenhum algorítmo (pelo menos já tentei uns 4)

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75350/ajax-cross-domain

Esta foi a pergunta que fiz, espero que não caia em duplicata pois achei bem específico o meu problema.

Comment: Parece me bem a pergunta.

Comment: @Felipe - É, se é um problema novo, nova pergunta. E ficar com o dedo no gatilho pra oferecer uma recompensa caso necessário. *Problem, dead or alive!*